# Custom options operations

Tags: custom-options

My client needs to make an operation on products custom options.

Using Magento CE, I create a product, and give it some custom options from within the built-in left hand side menu in "Manage products" > "Add new product", such as "mm" (millimeters) and "mt" (meters)

This product will have both radio options and a textbot input.

Let's say we have

```
Base price: 0 

MM:
Radio option A which costs 0,9
Radio option B which costs 1,2
Radio option C which costs 2,3 

MT:
Textbox value = unknown yet
```

Let's say user chooses `Radio option B` and enters `10` in the textfield

Price should be updates as such:

```
1,2 * 10 + 0
```

Which is

```
radio value cost * textbox value + base price
```

Is there any way to tell the code to take the value of the radio button, multiply it for the value of the textbox and sum it all to the base price?

Where could I look to see the current behavior of a product's custom options?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i have update answer,please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case,you can use magento [`event/observer`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).
Basically  there are two events,by which you can change the cart price of that products:

1. `checkout_cart_product_add_after`
2. `checkout_cart_update_items_after`
3. `checkout_cart_product_update_after`

This 3 event is need because of:

### Event1:checkout_cart_product_add_after

This event is fire when `first time a product is cart for current session` of current input values from frontend

### Event2:checkout_cart_product_update_after

This event is fire when `a current exiting cart item` edited from  **edit** link  of  cart item.

### Event3:checkout_cart_update_items_after

This event is fire whenever cart items update from cart page.

**As per as magento system,** a `cart item price` change using `setter` functions `setCustomPrice(), setOriginalCustomPrice` of cart item Object.

**Just like:**

```
$EachCartitem->setCustomPrice($price);
$EachCartitem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
// Enable super mode on the product.
$EachCartitem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

And using `events fire an observer` which is `calculate price basic of your input fields`.

[image]

**Suppose:** The `radio button` field name is `My Checkbox` and Text Box field Name is `MyTestext`.

**Config.xml code like:**

```
  <global>
    <models>
      <magento65569>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento65569_Model</class>
      </magento65569>
    </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_cart_product_add_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento65569/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>CalculatePrice</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
      <checkout_cart_update_items_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_update_items_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento65569/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>UpdateCalculatePrice</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </checkout_cart_update_items_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_update_items_after>
        <checkout_cart_product_update_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_product_update_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento65569/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>ExitingcartItemUpdate</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </checkout_cart_product_update_after_handler>
        </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_update_after>
            </events>
  </global>
```

**Observer code like this:**

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento65569_Model_Observer
{

        /* This function will work when product will cart */ 
            public function CalculatePrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                //Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after', array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));
                $RadioVal=0;
                $TextVal=0;
                $resultParams=array();
                $Event = $observer->getEvent();
                $product=$Event->getProduct();
                $quote_item=$Event->getQuoteItem();
                $item = ($quote_item->getParentItem()?$quote_item->getParentItem():$quote_item );
                $this->getOptiondata($item,$product);

            }
            /*  This function will work when cart item  will   qty  update */
            public function UpdateCalculatePrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
                 // Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_before', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));
                 $cart=$observer->getEvent()->getCart();
                 $data=$observer->getEvent()->getInfo();
                 foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemInfo) {
                 $quote_item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
                    if (!$quote_item) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $item = ($quote_item->getParentItem()?$quote_item->getParentItem():$quote_item );
                    $customOptions = $quote_item->getBuyRequest()->getOptions();
                    Mage::log(print_r($customOptions,1),null,'UpdateCalculatePrice.log');
                    $this->getOptiondata($item,$item->getProduct());
                 }


            }
            public function ExitingcartItemUpdate($observer){
              /*Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_update_after', array(
                        'quote_item' => $result,
                        'product' => $product
                    ));*/
                $Event = $observer->getEvent();
                $product=$Event->getProduct();
                $quote_item=$Event->getQuoteItem();
                $item = ($quote_item->getParentItem()?$quote_item->getParentItem():$quote_item );
                $this->getOptiondata($item,$product);



            }


            private function getOptiondata($item,$product){
                $RadioVal=0;
                $TextVal=0;
                $resultParams=array();

                $customOptions = $item->getBuyRequest()->getOptions();
                Mage::log(print_r($customOptions,1),null,'Customoption.log');

                if(is_array($customOptions)){
                    foreach ($customOptions as $key => $value) {
                        if ($value != '') {
                            $resultParams[]=$this->Recalculate($key,$value,$product);
                        }
                    }


                    if(!empty($resultParams)):
                        foreach($resultParams as $Each):
                            foreach($Each as $key=>$val):
                                if($key=='radio'):
                                $RadioVal=$val;
                                elseif($key=='mytext'):
                                $TextVal=$val;
                                else:
                                endif;

                            Mage::log(print_r($val,1),null,'new.log');
                            endforeach;
                        endforeach;

                        /* Now need price calcalute */
                        if($RadioVal!=0 && $TextVal!=0){
                            //radio value cost * textbox value + base price 
                            $price=($RadioVal*$TextVal)+($product->getPrice());
                            Mage::log($RadioVal.'ddddd'.$TextVal.'sss'.$price,null,'trrr.log');
                            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                            // Enable super mode on the product.
                            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);


                        }
                    endif;

                }



            }
            public function Recalculate($optionId=null,$SelectVal,$product){
                $Array=array();
                if($optionId):
                $option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->load($optionId);


                 if ($option = $product->getOptionById($optionId)) {
                             // Set additional fields to each type group
                            switch ($option->getGroupByType()) {
                                    case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_GROUP_TEXT:
                                        if($option->getTitle()=='MyTestext'):
                                            $Array['mytext']=$SelectVal;
                                            Mage::log(print_r($Array,1),null,'Customoptionr.log');
                                        endif;

                                    break;
                                case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_GROUP_SELECT:
                                    if($option->getTitle()=='My Checkbox'):
                                        foreach ($option->getValuesCollection() as $value) {
    /*                                      'value_id' => $value->getId(),
                                            'title' => $value->getTitle(),
                                            'price' => $value->getPrice(),
                                            'price_type' => $value->getPriceType(),
                                            'sku' => $value->getSku(),
                                            'sort_order' => $value->getSortOrder()
    */                                      if($value->getId()==$SelectVal){
                                                $Array['radio']=$value->getPrice();
                                            Mage::log(print_r($Array,1),null,'Customoptionr.log');


                                            }

                                        }
                                    endif;  
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                 }
                 /* end of $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId) */
                endif;
                return $Array;
            }



}
```

### Full Module:

As per as  your request, i have put full module:

**File1:** create `config file` at a`pp/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento65569/etc/config.xml`

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento65569>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento65569>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <magento65569>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento65569_Model</class>
      </magento65569>
    </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_cart_product_add_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento65569/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>CalculatePrice</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
      <checkout_cart_update_items_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_update_items_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento65569/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>UpdateCalculatePrice</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </checkout_cart_update_items_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_update_items_after>
        <checkout_cart_product_update_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_product_update_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento65569/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>ExitingcartItemUpdate</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </checkout_cart_product_update_after_handler>
        </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_update_after>
            </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**File2:** location `app/code/local/Stackexchange/Magento65569/Model/Observer.php`

**Code:**

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento65569_Model_Observer
{

            public function CalculatePrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                $RadioVal=0;
                $TextVal=0;
                $resultParams=array();
                $Event = $observer->getEvent();
                $product=$Event->getProduct();
                $quote_item=$Event->getQuoteItem();
                $item = ($quote_item->getParentItem()?$quote_item->getParentItem():$quote_item );
                $this->getOptiondata($item,$product);

            }
            /*  This function will work when cart item  will   qty  update */
            public function UpdateCalculatePrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
                 $cart=$observer->getEvent()->getCart();
                 $data=$observer->getEvent()->getInfo();
                 foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemInfo) {
                 $quote_item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
                    if (!$quote_item) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $item = ($quote_item->getParentItem()?$quote_item->getParentItem():$quote_item );
                    $customOptions = $quote_item->getBuyRequest()->getOptions();
                    Mage::log(print_r($customOptions,1),null,'UpdateCalculatePrice.log');
                    $this->getOptiondata($item,$item->getProduct());
                 }


            }
            public function ExitingcartItemUpdate($observer){
                $Event = $observer->getEvent();
                $product=$Event->getProduct();
                $quote_item=$Event->getQuoteItem();
                $item = ($quote_item->getParentItem()?$quote_item->getParentItem():$quote_item );
                $this->getOptiondata($item,$product);

            }


            private function getOptiondata($item,$product){
                $RadioVal=0;
                $TextVal=0;
                $resultParams=array();

                $customOptions = $item->getBuyRequest()->getOptions();

                if(is_array($customOptions)){
                    foreach ($customOptions as $key => $value) {
                        if ($value != '') {
                            $resultParams[]=$this->Recalculate($key,$value,$product);
                        }
                    }


                    if(!empty($resultParams)):
                        foreach($resultParams as $Each):
                            foreach($Each as $key=>$val):
                                if($key=='radio'):
                                $RadioVal=$val;
                                elseif($key=='mytext'):
                                $TextVal=$val;
                                else:
                                endif;

                            Mage::log(print_r($val,1),null,'new.log');
                            endforeach;
                        endforeach;

                        /* Now need price calcalute */
                        if($RadioVal!=0 && $TextVal!=0){
                            //radio value cost * textbox value + base price 
                            $price=($RadioVal*$TextVal)+($product->getPrice());
                            Mage::log($RadioVal.'ddddd'.$TextVal.'sss'.$price,null,'trrr.log');
                            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                            // Enable super mode on the product.
                            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);


                        }
                    endif;

                }



            }
            public function Recalculate($optionId=null,$SelectVal,$product){
                $Array=array();
                if($optionId):
                $option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->load($optionId);


                 if ($option = $product->getOptionById($optionId)) {
                             // Set additional fields to each type group
                            switch ($option->getGroupByType()) {
                                    case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_GROUP_TEXT:
                                        if($option->getTitle()=='MyTestext'):
                                            $Array['mytext']=$SelectVal;
                                            Mage::log(print_r($Array,1),null,'Customoptionr.log');
                                        endif;

                                    break;
                                case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_GROUP_SELECT:
                                    if($option->getTitle()=='My Checkbox'):
                                        foreach ($option->getValuesCollection() as $value) {
                                            if($value->getId()==$SelectVal){
                                                $Array['radio']=$value->getPrice();
                                            Mage::log(print_r($Array,1),null,'Customoptionr.log');


                                            }

                                        }
                                    endif;  
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                 }
                 /* end of $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId) */
                endif;
                return $Array;
            }



}
```

**File3:** Module Main file at `app/etc/modules/Stackexchange_Magento65569.xml`

**code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento65569>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento65569>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for this answer, before I'll go ahead and try it, I have a question: can custom option have a name, as you said as an example "my checkbox" and "my txtfield"? I saw that they are named dinamically, am I wrong or?

Comment: hi ,i  have create text field  name of `MyTesrtext` and  checkbox field  name  of `My Checkbox` .

Comment: Can this be done using Product's custom options? I'm pretty new to this, I'm sorry if I bother you.

Comment: i  will help with full module shortly