# Custom Product Type and `getPrice()`

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, custom-product-type

In my custom product type model, I have:

```
public function prepareForCartAdvanced(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product = null, $processMode) {
    $product->setMyProperty(500);
    return parent::prepareForCartAdvanced($buyRequest, $product, $processMode);
}
```

In my product type's price model, I have:

```
public function getPrice($product) {
    // This displays 500
    echo $product->getMyProperty();
    exit;
    // This does not return 500 - the product's price in cart is 0.00
    return $product->getMyProperty();
    // This does return 500 - the product's price in cart is 500.00
    return 500;
}
```

**Why can I not return `$product->getMyProperty()` even though the value I have set is properly echoed?**

No matter what I do, I am only able to set the return price if I key a number in directly. I cannot set any value in the price model based on something passed through `$product`.

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting to you create Custom attribute  of type price name as `my_property` from Backend  as `getPrice()` is  `always return a numeric value`.

Also, don't use  prepareForCartAdvanced() for this case.If want to change the price of product basic of an attribute then

use magento [`event/observer`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).
Basically  there are two events,by which you can change the cart price of that products:

1. `checkout_cart_product_add_after`
2. `checkout_cart_update_items_after`
3. `checkout_cart_product_update_after`

As per as magento system, a cart item price change using setter functions setCustomPrice(), setOriginalCustomPrice of cart item Object.

**Just like:**

```
$EachCartitem->setCustomPrice($price);
$EachCartitem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
// Enable super mode on the product.
$EachCartitem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

An example: [Custom options operations](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65569/custom-options-operations)

Comment: The reason I have a custom product type in the first place is because a price attribute cannot be used (decimal precision is not sufficient). Why do I need to use an observer to set the price of a custom product type? Isn't that precisely what a custom price model is for?

Comment: You could enhance the decimal precision of prices throughout your DB. It is a painful process (trust me, I've done it), and you'd have to override lots of Magento models to get it working, but it's feasible.