# Price update in Add to cart functionality from product detail page to cart page

Tags: price, addtocart, quantity

Can anyone tell me in magento, when we click **Add to Cart** button in product detail page, where and how is **Product Price** and **Qty** input multiplied and updated in **shopping cart** page **Subtotal** column. I want to customize the action for my custom pricing module.

Comment: what you mean by `customize the action for my custom pricing module.`

Comment: By default, magento takes the **prod price** and **qty** as separate parameters and multiply them during **Add to Cart** event to display **subtotal** in cart page. But I am performing custom price calculation in product page itself and updating the custom price using ajax. Now I want my custom price to be displayed in cart page sub total column alone. But the same price is displayed both in unit **price** and **subtotal** columns. Also I want to **prevent default multiply action** on Add to cart.

Comment: Amit pl let me know if u can help me with this issue.

Comment: that means you can change cart item price and subtotal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtotal logic on the cart page is implemented in the below template file.

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

Override this file into your local and modify it as per your requirement.

Comment: thank you for the reply.. can u pls tell me how does the subtotal in cart page logic goes in while clicking **Add to Cart** in PDP **(product price * qty)**

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: btw is it poss for u to answer my another query too?

Answer (score 1):

Guess that

You  want to change cart item unit price.I

So in this case,you can use magento [`event/observer`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).
Basically  there are two events,by which you can change the cart price of that products:

1. `checkout_cart_product_add_after`
2. `checkout_cart_update_items_after`
3. `checkout_cart_product_update_after`

This 3 event is need because of:

### Event1:checkout_cart_product_add_after

This event is fire when `first time a product is cart for current session` of current input values from frontend

### Event2:checkout_cart_product_update_after

This event is fire when `a current exiting cart item` edited from  **edit** link  of  cart item.

### Event3:checkout_cart_update_items_after

This event is fire whenever cart items update from cart page.

**As per as magento system,** a `cart item price` change using `setter` functions `setCustomPrice(), setOriginalCustomPrice` of cart item Object.

**Just like:**

```
$EachCartitem->setCustomPrice($price);
$EachCartitem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
// Enable super mode on the product.
$EachCartitem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

If you can cart each unit price then automatically change subtotal

An example: [Custom options operations](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65569/custom-options-operations)

Comment: Thank u Amit. I have set the new price and it's updated in quote table using event/obs. The problem is, I'm changing the Prod Price displayed in my pdp using ajax when my customer enters a number. Along with tat I'm using several parameters and calculating the custom prod price. It's updated in the same div where magento displays the unit price frm backend. So when I add to cart, the unit price in cart is getting updated as my custom price. I wanna stop it. Also I need to prevent the **prod price * qty** functionality.